# np.genfromtxt (got 38 columns instead of 38)?

Tags: python, numpy

```
self.logdata = np.genfromtxt(name, skip_header = 7, usecols = np.arange(1, self.logRs + 2))
```

Hi, I am using np.genfromtxt to get data from a .data file, and it's giving me a value error for each line saying '(got 38 columns instead of 38).' I can fix the error by only using 37 columns (changing self.logRs + 2 to self.logRs + 1; self.logRs is equal to 37 in this case), but then I don't get the last column of the file.

I've been unable to find anyone with a similar issue online. Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How  many columns in the file?  Any lines different?

Comment: I can reproduce errors like that with a file that contains 3 columns and I try `genfromtxt(file, usecols=range(1, 4))`.  Column numbering starts at 0; are you intentionally skipping the first column?  Can you add the first two or three lines of the file to the question?